# Force.com site Guest User unable to access events

Tags: force.com-sites, event, guest-user

I am having hard trying to give access for the Force.com site Guest user to all contact events in the org.

When the contact is assigned to the Guest User, he does have access to his events.

But if the contact is assigned to a real user in the org, he doesn't.

Here how I tried to solve it but in vain:
I have given the Guest user read/write permissions on events through a permissions set.
I created two public groups, one containing real users and the other containing the guest user.
Then I created a sharing rule, to enable sharing of contacts assigned to users in the first public group with the second public group containing the guest user.

Am I missing anything?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you OWD for Event and Contact and how are Contacts shared?

Comment: There is also a concept of internal and external sharing rules that was introduced recently that caught me out - check the external sharing rules are enabled to work with the guest user

Comment: @crmprogdev Activity is "Controlled By Parent" and Contacts is "public read/write". I made contacts to be shared through sharing rule, between the 2 public groups.